# Sorting 2 arrays row wise using quick_sort

Tags: c++

I'm given 2 arrays, one that contains first names and another that contains last names. So far, I've been able to sort the last names alphabetically while retaining the corresponding the first name. The problem I have are with the duplicate last names. My goal is to first sort the last names, then if a group of people have the same last name, I want to sort their first names while keeping the rest of the array untouched.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#define NUM_PEOPLE 10

void swap(string *array1, string *array2, int index1, int index2) {
    string temp1 = array1[index1];
    array1[index1] = array1[index2];
    array1[index2] = temp1;
   
    string temp2 = array2[index1];
    array2[index1] = array2[index2];
    array2[index2] = temp2;
   
}

int compare(string last1, string last2, string first1, string first2) {
    return (last1.compare(last2));
}


int quick_sort(string list1[], string list2[], int start, int end) {
   
   int low = start;
   int high = end;
   string pivot = list1[end];
   
   do {
      while ((low < high) && (compare(list1[low], pivot, list2[low], list2[end]) <= 0))
         low++;
     
      while ((high > low) && (compare(list1[high], pivot, list2[low], list2[end]) >= 0))
         high--;
         
      
      if (low < high)
         swap(list1, list2, low, high);
        
     
   } while (low < high);
   if (low != end)
      swap(list1, list2, low, end);
   
   if (low - 1 > start)
      quick_sort(list1, list2, start, low - 1);
   
   if (end > low + 1)
      quick_sort(list1, list2, low + 1, end);
}


int main(){
    string first_names[] =   {"Kwame",
                              "Moesha",
                              "Loren",
                              "Elicia",
                              "Cathy",
                              "Aiesha",
                              "Amie",
                              "Saim",
                              "Dilara",
                              "Alessia" };
    
    string last_names[] =    {"Sanders",
                              "Cooper",
                              "Rangel",
                              "Cooper",
                              "Wang",
                              "Cooper",
                              "Jarvis",
                              "Fritz",
                              "Workman",
                              "Gould" };
    
    quick_sort(last_names, first_names, 0, NUM_PEOPLE - 1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PEOPLE; i++)
       cout << first_names[i] << "\t" << last_names[i] << endl;   
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason to not to use standard library sort function ?

Comment: I'm required to include quick_sort. @joker007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty much correct , You will need to update your compare function to something like this .

```
int compare(string last1, string last2, string first1, string first2)
{
    if(last1 == last2)
        return first1 < first2;
    else return last1 < last2;
}
```

Here first last names are compared if they they are same then only first names are compared .
This function returns 1 if full name 1 < full name 2 and returns 0 if full name 1 >= full name 2

You also need to modify while loops in quick_sort function which are using this compare function .

```
while ((low < high) && (compare(list1[low], pivot, list2[low], list2[end]) == 1))
            low++;

while ((high > low) && (compare(list1[high], pivot, list2[high], list2[end]) == 0))
            high--;
```

One mistake was that in the 2nd while loop , you were using arguments `(list1[high] , pivot , list2[low],list2[end])` but `list1[high]` and `list2[low]` don't represent the same name , thus it should be `list2[high]` .
And also , now comparisions have 1 or 0 , rather than <=0 or >0 , as now the compare function returns boolean value (true or false , 1 or 0 , yada yada)

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for like a couple hours now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one pass, with the proper compare function.

You should pass strings by reference to your compare function, and make it as fast as possible. Making copies will slow down your sort quite a bit, as will unnecessary comparisons.

```
int compare(const string& last1, const string& last2, const string& first1, const string& first2) {
    int result = last1.compare(last2);
    if (result == 0)
        result = first1.compare(first2);
    return result;
}
```